# Disabling the option "Enable authentication for '/project' end-point" in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ci

We are working on a monorepo in GitLab which has 100s of branches. We use Jenkins for CI, and the tooling decision is made by different stakeholders and I don't want to go to the details of that. We use GitLab webhooks to trigger the builds in Jenkins when a new branch is pushed. The scanning of the branches take forever - almost 30 to 90 minutes. We disabled the checkbox: "Enable authentication for '/project' end-point" in manage Jenkins and boom the branch index scan is taking seconds now.

As per the documentation https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html disabling this option allows anybody knowing the url of the hook to trigger a job. I tried to make the webhook POST call (as explained here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html#with-a-webhook) by both enabling and disabling this option through Postman and I am able to make the calls. What are the downsides of disabling this option?

Answer (score 1):

> What are the downsides of disabling this option?

Disabling this option removes an authentication layer, potentially allowing unauthorized users to trigger Jenkins jobs if they have knowledge of the URL of the hook. That is a significant security risk, especially if Jenkins is exposed to the public internet.
If not, this is not as bad.

With the absence of authentication, there is a risk of abuse: malicious actors could continuously trigger builds, thereby consuming resources and possibly leading to Denial of Service (DoS) situations.

The integrity of your builds could be compromised if unauthorized users can trigger jobs. It is important to make sure only authorized and validated sources can initiate build processes to maintain the reliability and correctness of your CI pipeline.

Authentication also plays a role in auditing and accountability. When authentication is enforced, it is easier to track who or what triggered a job, aiding in investigations or audits.

If your organization has to adhere to certain compliance standards, disabling authentication could lead to non-compliance, especially those standards that require stringent access controls and auditing capabilities.

Jenkins provides a way to [enforce granular access control](https://plugins.jenkins.io/matrix-auth/), ensuring that only users with the appropriate permissions can [trigger certain jobs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/build-authorization/). Disabling the authentication for the '/project' endpoint might bypass some of these controls, making your setup less secure.

If unauthorized users can trigger jobs, they might also be able to access or expose sensitive information processed by these jobs, depending on the job configuration and the level of access control enforced elsewhere in your Jenkins setup.

---

> I am able to make `POST` call in both cases when the authentication option is checked and unchecked. I am trying to understand the real impact of disabling this change.

The real impact of disabling the "Enable authentication for '`/project`' end-point" option in Jenkins could potentially lead to unauthorized access or abuse if malicious actors discover the webhook URL.

However, the exact behavior might depend on other configurations within Jenkins or network-level controls.

Since you can make `POST` calls in both cases, this particular authentication option might not be the only security measure in place. Do analyze the entire security setup, including network firewalls, reverse proxies, and other Jenkins security configurations, to understand the full impact of disabling this authentication option.

- **Network Firewalls**:for instance, a misconfiguration allowing traffic from untrusted networks could expose Jenkins to potential attackers.
- **Reverse Proxies**: If, for instance, SSL/TLS is improperly configured, sensitive data like authentication credentials could be transmitted insecurely.
- **Jenkins Security Configurations**: Disabling authentication for the '`/project`' endpoint could allow unauthorized users to trigger potentially malicious builds, especially if there are no other access control measures in place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am able to make POST call in both cases when the authentication option is checked and unchecked. I am trying to understand the real impact of disabling this change.

Comment: @ChandanNJ I have edited the answer to address your comment.